# regEx expression variable length numeric string

Tags: regex

Need to filter all items that contains string of three parts:

```
1. "MSG
2. any length string that contains number or zero length string
3. contains `+` character
```

example `MSG123+`

How to write this in regEx?

I was trying something like this `"MSG*+` , but this was not expected one?

Comment: So, `*` was supposed to match *any text containing a digit*? Those requirements sound unclear to me compared to the example string. Try `"MSG((?=.*[+]).*[0-9].*)?` or `"MSG(.*[0-9].*)?[+]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp for this depends on what software is being used but

```
"MSG[0-9]*\+
```

Is likely to work

[0-9] means any character 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

* means any number including zero of the previous character

+ escapes the plus sign in most implementations.  + means "one or more of the previous character" in extended regexp syntax - this is fairly standard